# Master detail using EF 4 in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Using Northwind database as Entity data model, I have dragged from datasource window 2 datagridview controls containing Orders and Order_details, and dropped them on a windows Form. When running the project I get only Orders Gridview populated, and not sorted. The code I used in Form load event is next:

```
        using(NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities())
        {

        ordersDataGridView.DataSource = context.Orders;
        ordersBindingSource.Sort = "CustomerID ASC";

        order_DetailsDataGridView.DataSource = order_DetailsBindingSource;

        }
```

How can I make the details Grid display item related to the selected Order entity, and how can I sort the order Grid? Thank you.

Comment: What is `order_DetailsBindingSource`? Where does it come from?

Comment: order_DetailsBindingSource is generated automaticaly when dragged and dropped the Orders datagrid on the form.

Comment: Can you show us the markup code for the order_detailsbindingsource and ordersdatagridview?

Answer (score 0):

1. Displaying related items of select order in details Grid should work automatically, without any addition code. Please, check BindingSource.DataSource propery of your details bindingsource. It should contain name of your master bindingsource.
2. You can use linq query to sort your orders:

   ordersDataGridView.DataSource = context.Orders.OrderBy(o => o.CustomerID);

Comment: 1. I have checked the BindingSource.DataSource property of my details bindingsource. It already contain name of the master bindingsource (ordersBindingSource).

Comment: 1. still not showing data.     2.Your second part of the answer is right, thank you.